# Multiple fields update in a model using radio boxes

Tags: django

I am trying to make a page where admin can mark attendance for each student using absent and present radio boxes present besides each student

My ClassRoom and ClassRoomStudents Model

```py
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    # standard = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classSection = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(Teacher, on_delete = models.CASCADE)


class ClassRoomStudent(models.Model):
    classRoom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roll_number = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.OneToOneField(StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def save (self, *args, **kwargs):
        <logic to update roll number automatically for each classroom_student>
```

model.py in my attendence app, status will store absent or present

```
class StudentAttendence(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoomStudent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()


class TeacherAttendence(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
```

I have option in my template to search students using class.

My views.py in attendence app

```py
def student_attendence(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if "add_no" in request.GET:
            add_no = request.GET["add_no"]
            students = ClassRoomStudent.objects.filter(classRoom__classSection__icontains = class_name)
            return render(request, 'attendence/student.html', {"students":students})
```

My question is how can I mark each student as absent or present using radiobox or something and store that in StudentAttendence model for each student?

Comment: `StudentAttendence` has a `OneToOneField` to `ClassRoomStudent` which means that you can't have multiple entries in your attendance model for each student for each day?

Comment: @IainShelvington oh yes I should chnage it to one to many with ClassRoomStudent.